# Getting values from select box

Tags: php, sql, insert

For my internship, I am creating a scoreboard list for the people in the break, to keep track of all the wins. I am using MVC.

I have the following tables:

Players (p_id **PK**, name)

Games (game_id **PK**, p_id *FK*) *-> p_id foreign key with players.p_id*

Winners (game_id *FK*, p_id *FK*) *-> game_id FK with games.game_id, p_id FK with players.p_id*

For example, I create a game with Player1 & Player2. I now need to add the winner. I made a separate page, that links to a form where you can select one of those players and Insert it into the winner's table.

My form looks like this:

```
 <form method="post" action="<?php echo ROOT ?>HomeController/winnerBilliard/" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="form-group">
        <label for="player_1">Select game number</label><br>
        <select class="form-control" name="game_id">
            <option selected value="<?php echo $selectedGame['id']; ?>"><?php echo $selectedGame[0]['id']; ?></option>  
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="player_1">Select winner</label><br>
        <select class="form-control" name="option">
            <option disabled selected value>Choose winner</option>
            <option value="<?php echo $selectedGame['player_1']; ?>"><?php echo $selectedGame[0]['player_1']; ?></option> 
            <option value="<?php echo $selectedGame['player_2']; ?>"><?php echo $selectedGame[0]['player_2']; ?></option> 
        </select>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" name="create">Add winner</button>
</form>
```

My method looks like this:

```
public function winnerBilliard() {
    if(isset($_POST["create"])) {
        $game = $_POST['id'];
        $option = $_POST['option'];
        // var_dump($option); exit();
        $query = "INSERT INTO billiard_winners (id,winner) VALUES ('$game','$option')";
        $this->model->create($query);
        Header('Location: ' . ROOT . 'HomeController/billiardGames');
    } 
}
```

My create method in my model looks like this:

```
public function create($query)
{   

    $data = $this->db->insert($query);

    return $data;
}
```

For some reason, it ain't reading the values. If I vardump the query in my create method, I will see this on my screen:

> string(55) "INSERT INTO billiard_winners (id,winner) VALUES ('','')"

That means it is not reading the $game & $option for some reason. But why?

---

I think I know where the mistake is.

My method to INSERT is:

```
public function winnerGames() {
    if(isset($_POST["create"])) {
        $game = $_POST['id'];
        $option = $_POST['option'];

        $query = "INSERT INTO winners (id,winner) VALUES ('$game','$option')";
        $this->model->create($query);


        Header('Location: ' . ROOT . 'HomeController/Games');
    } 
}
```

My method to get to the right page and fill the options with the values is:

```
public function editGame($id) {
    $getGame = "SELECT * FROM games WHERE id = $id";
    $selectedGame = $this->model->readAll($getGame, $id);
    include('app/views/editGame.php');
}
```

I think my method is trying to get the games from $selectedGame, but isn't able to look into that method. Is that true?

Comment: `name` attribute should be on the `select` element not the `option` element and each `select` should have unique name.

Comment: Yup, I've found out haha. I edited my code, because it's still not reading it. I put the name attribute in both options.

Comment: Your form uses `game_id` for the game number but your code appears to be looking for `id`.

Comment: @Nick I thought I was going crazy there. I can't see an edit...

Comment: @Dave it is now using both id, but still not working.

Comment: Right after `if(isset($_POST["create"])) {` do a `var_dump($_POST);` and make sure it contains what you are expecting.

Comment: @Dave Receiving an empty array

Comment: Well that would certainly explain why you aren't getting the values you are expecting. Suggest you look at the rendered source of your page and make sure the form tag details are correct.

Comment: Added more code. I think my mistake is in the methods. I am getting the values that are already in the form in the options with the editGame method. I try to INSERT values from that method into another, if you know what I mean. I think that's not possible

Answer (score 0):

You should map your element names with $_POST, recheck that,
You should avoid using element tags as property names of elements(e.g. should avoid option as name of select).
Use [print_r](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) to debug posted data in php.

I think you are missing trick here,

```
$saveArr['id'] = $_POST['id'];
$saveArr['winner'] = $_POST['option'];
$this->model->create($saveArr);
```

Now in create method,

```
public function create($saveArr){
    $data = $this->db->insert($saveArr);
}
```

This should work.